# Cannot use wkhtmltopdf in Docker image php:8.0-fpm-alpine

Tags: php, docker, wkhtmltopdf, alpine-linux, sylius

I am using `php:8.0-fpm-alpine3.14` Docker image in which I have a Sylius project and I would like use `wkhtmltopdf`, so I followed these links:

- https://sasablagojevic.com/setting-up-wkhtmltopdf-on-docker-alpine-linux
- https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/packaging/issues/2#issuecomment-725962861

So I currently have this Docker image:

```
FROM php:8.0-fpm-alpine3.14 AS sylius_php

# persistent / runtime deps
RUN apk add --no-cache \
        acl \
        file \
        gettext \
        git \
        mariadb-client \
    ;

ARG APCU_VERSION=5.1.17
RUN set -eux; \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        $PHPIZE_DEPS \
        coreutils \
        freetype-dev \
        icu-dev \
        libjpeg-turbo-dev \
        libpng-dev \
        libtool \
        libwebp-dev \
        libzip-dev \
        mariadb-dev \
    ; \
    \
    docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-jpeg --with-webp --with-freetype; \
    docker-php-ext-configure zip --with-zip; \
    docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) \
        exif \
        gd \
        intl \
        pdo \
        pdo_mysql \
        zip \
    ; \
    pecl install \
        apcu-${APCU_VERSION} \
    ; \
    pecl clear-cache; \
    docker-php-ext-enable \
        apcu \
        opcache \
    ; \
    \
    runDeps="$( \
        scanelf --needed --nobanner --format '%n#p' --recursive /usr/local/lib/php/extensions \
            | tr ',' '\n' \
            | sort -u \
            | awk 'system("[ -e /usr/local/lib/" $1 " ]") == 0 { next } { print "so:" $1 }' \
    )"; \
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .sylius-phpexts-rundeps $runDeps; \
    \
    apk del .build-deps

COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer
COPY docker/php/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
COPY docker/php/php-cli.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php-cli.ini

RUN apk --update --no-cache add \
   wkhtmltopdf \
    libgcc \
    libstdc++ \
    musl \
    qt5-qtbase \
    qt5-qtbase-x11 \
    qt5-qtsvg \
    qt5-qtwebkit \
    ttf-freefont \
    ttf-dejavu \
    ttf-droid \
    ttf-liberation \
    xvfb \
    fontconfig

# Add openssl dependencies for wkhtmltopdf
RUN echo 'https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.8/main' >> /etc/apk/repositories && \
    apk add --no-cache libcrypto1.0 libssl1.0

RUN ln -s /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf;
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf;

# https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#composer-allow-superuser
ENV COMPOSER_ALLOW_SUPERUSER=1
RUN set -eux; \
    composer clear-cache
ENV PATH="${PATH}:/root/.composer/vendor/bin"

WORKDIR /srv/sylius

COPY docker/php/docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint

ENTRYPOINT ["docker-entrypoint"]
CMD ["php-fpm"]
```

The installation of `wkhtmltopdf` is ok but I get the following error when I run `bin/console sylius:install -s plus` command:

[image]

I don't understand why I get that error et how to fix that.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

According to [wkhtmltopdf FAQ](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html#:%7E:text=incompatible%20libc%3A%20not,worked%20on%20Alpine.), it is not supposed to work properly in the alpine distro.

Anyway, the `sylius-logo.png` image from the HTML seems not to be accessible when trying to build the pdf, indicating a redirect status.